# How can I find the smallest covering prefix of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> Find the first covering prefix of a given array.
>
> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The first covering
>   prefix of array A is the smallest integer P such that  and such that every value that
>   occurs in array A also occurs in sequence.
>
> For example, the first covering prefix of array A with
>   A[0]=2, A[1]=2, A[2]=1, A[3]=0,  A[4]=1 is 3, because sequence A[0],
>   A[1], A[2], A[3] equal to 2, 2, 1, 0 contains all values that occur in
>   array A.

My solution is

```
int ps ( int[] A ) 
{
    int largestvalue=0;
    int index=0;   

    for(each element in Array){
        if(A[i]>largestvalue)
        {
            largestvalue=A[i];
            index=i;
        }
    }

    for(each element in Array)
    {
        if(A[i]==index)
            index=i; 
    }   
    return index;
}
```

But this only works for this input, this is not a generalized solution.

Comment: Uhhhh, whats the purpose of the second for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531553/php-code-to-find-first-covering-prefix-of-an-array

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate as this is not language specific

Comment: "such that and such that" I think you didn't write one of the conditions

Comment: @antti.huima: was that sarcasm?

Comment: @noob No, why? I voted to close this as duplicate.

Comment: The original question also says:
        expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
        expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

Comment: Oh, and the requirement is to have `O(N)` space and time complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this

```
int coveringPrefixIndex(final int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> indexes = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    // start from the back
    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        indexes.put(arr[i],i);
    }
    // now find the highest value in the map
    int highestIndex = 0;
    for(Integer i : indexes.values()) {
        if(highestIndex < i.intValue()) highestIndex = i.intValue();
    }
    return highestIndex;
}
```

Comment: @Raj that's a good point. I'll fix it for future reference. Thanks for that.

Comment: I think you need to look out for duplicate elements case. This solution wouldn't work if your prefix ends then you get a repeated element. I'd add an 'if' condition in the first 'for' loop to find if you've already inserted an item. If so, then update the value with the lower index.

Comment: @mbadawi23 If you notice, it iterates from the end backwards, so it automatically replaces with the lower index. :-)

Comment: Can you explain what is covering prefix of an array is? I am unable to understand from the above definition

Comment: @BilalAhmad The covering prefix is how far into the array you must go before you have seen all unique values of the array. If all your values are the same, your covering prefix is at index 0. If you have all unique values, your covering prefix is the entire array. Imagine you added all the values of the array to a set. This gives you all the unique values of the array. Now start from the beginning of the array again and start adding them to a new set. How far into the array must you go in order to make your new set the same size as the old set?

Answer (score 9):

**Got 100% with the below.**

```
public int ps (int[] a)
    {
        var length = a.Length;
        var temp = new HashSet<int>();
        var result = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            if (!temp.Contains(a[i]))
            {
                temp.Add(a[i]);
                result = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The best solution here... I did something similar, but I went other way round: created an array of unique values and was removing values from it as I found them, when it got to Count == 0, that was the prefix... got only 94% for that thugh.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes that would work as well. I think because you are adding and removing, it may be slightly less efficient then looking up and adding which I am using. Even though they are all o(1) operations for hashsets. I am curious to know which condition did it deduct the 6% for?

Comment: Detected time complexity:
O(N) or O(N*log(N))

Comment: @YuriyChernyshov This solution is O(N) complexity

Comment: I used the same logic except I chose Hashmap over hashset. I got only 88%. my performance % was only 81%. Any reason why? The performance degraded for 10,000 and 100,000 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is from *Alpha 2010 Start Challenge* of Codility platform. And here is my solution which got score of **100**. The idea is simple, I track an array of counters for the input array. Traversing the input array backwards, decrement the respective counter, if that counter becomes zero it means we have found the first covering prefix.

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    int size = A.length;
    int[] counters = new int[size];

    for (int a : A)
        counters[a]++;

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (--counters[A[i]] == 0)
            return i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the array has following values `[10, 0, 5, 0, 10]`? `counters[10]` should throw, right?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the note: `each element of array A is an integer in range [0..N-1].` Good job!

Answer (score 2):

here's my solution in C#:

```
public static int CoveringPrefix(int[] Array1)
    {
        // Step 1. Get length of Array1
        int Array1Length = 0;
        foreach (int i in Array1) Array1Length++;
        // Step 2. Create a second array with the highest value of the first array as its length
        int highestNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Array1Length; i++)
        {
            if (Array1[i] > highestNum) highestNum = Array1[i];
        }
        highestNum++;   // Make array compatible for our operation
        int[] Array2 = new int[highestNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < highestNum; i++) Array2[i] = 0; // Fill values with zeros
        // Step 3. Final operation will determine unique values in Array1 and return the index of the highest unique value
        int highestIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Array1Length; i++)
        {
            if (Array2[Array1[i]] < 1)
            {
                Array2[Array1[i]]++;
                highestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return highestIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

100p

```
public static int ps(int[] a) {
    Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (temp.add(a[i])) {
            p = i+1;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution as well

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class Solution {
    public int ps ( int[] A ) {
        Set set = new HashSet();
        int index =-1;

        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if(set.contains(A[i])){
                if(index==-1)
                    index = i;
            }else{
                index = i;
                set.add(A[i]);
            }         
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any Collection:
search the index of the first occurrence of each element,
the prefix is the maximum of that index. Do it backwards to finish early:

```
private static int prefix(int[] array) {
    int max = -1;
    int i = array.length - 1;
    while (i > max) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { // include i
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                if (j > max) {
                    max = j;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
    return max;
}

// TEST

private static void test(int... array) {
    int prefix = prefix(array);
    int[] segment = Arrays.copyOf(array, prefix+1);
    System.out.printf("%s = %d = %s%n", Arrays.toString(array), prefix, Arrays.toString(segment));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(2, 2, 1, 0, 1);
    test(2, 2, 1, 0, 4);
    test(2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2);
    test(1, 1, 1);
    test(1, 2, 3);
    test(4);
    test();  // empty array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried first. I got 24%

```
public int ps ( int[] A ) {
int n = A.length, i = 0, r = 0,j = 0;

for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
        if ((long) A[i] == (long) A[j]) {
            r += 1;
        }
        if (r == n) return i;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //method must be public for codility to access
public int solution(int A[]){
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(A.length);
    int index= A[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if( set.contains(A[i])) continue;
        index = i;
        set.add(A[i]);
    }   
    return index;
}
```

this got 100%, however detected time was O(N * log N) due to the HashSet.
your solutions without hashsets i don't really follow...

Answer (score 0):

shortest code possible in java:

```
    public static int solution(int A[]){
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(A.length);//avoid resizing
    int index= -1; //value does not matter;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
        if( !set.contains(A[i])) set.add(A[index = i]); //assignment + eval     
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got 100% with this one:

```
public int solution (int A[]){
    int index = -1;
    boolean found[] = new boolean[A.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        if (!found [A[i]] ){
            index = i;
            found [A[i]] = true;
        }

    return index;    
}
```

I used a boolean array which keeps track of the read elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in **Java** to achieve 100% correctness and 81% performance, using a list to store and compare the values with.

It wasn't quick enough to pass random_n_log_100000 random_n_10000 or random_n_100000 tests, but it is a correct answer.

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int N = A.length;
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(!temp.contains(A[i])){
            temp.add(A[i]);
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
        if(temp.contains(A[j])){
            temp.remove((Object)A[j]);
        }
        if(temp.isEmpty()){
            return j;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correctness and Performance: 100%:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
class Solution {

   public int solution(int[] inputArray)
   {
      int covering;
      int[] A = inputArray;
      int N = A.length;
      HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      covering = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      {
          if (map.get(A[i]) == null)
          {
              map.put(A[i], A[i]);
              covering = i;
          }
      }
      return covering;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Objective-C Solution to PrefixSet from Codility. 100% correctness and performance.

What can be changed to make it even more efficient? (without out using c code).

HOW IT WORKS:

Everytime I come across a number in the array I check to see if I have added it to the dictionary yet.

If it is in the dictionary then I know it is not a new number so not important in relation to the problem. If it is a new number that we haven't come across already, then I need to update the indexOftheLastPrefix to this array position and add it to the dictionary as a key.

It only used one for loop so takes just one pass. Objective-c code is quiet heavy so would like to hear of any tweaks to make this go faster. It did get 100% for performance though.

```
int solution(NSMutableArray *A)
```

{

```
NSUInteger arraySize = [A count];
NSUInteger indexOflastPrefix=0;

NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
{
    if ([myDict objectForKey:[[A objectAtIndex:i]stringValue]])
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [myDict setValue:@"YES" forKey:[[A objectAtIndex:i]stringValue]];
        indexOflastPrefix = i;
    }
}

return indexOflastPrefix;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

int solution(vector &A) {
    // write your code in C++11 (g++ 4.8.2)

```
int max = 0, min = -1;

int maxindex =0,minindex = 0;

min = max =A[0];

for(unsigned int i=1;i<A.size();i++)
{

    if(max < A[i] )
    {
      max = A[i];
      maxindex =i;

    } 
     if(min > A[i])
     {
         min =A[i];
         minindex = i;
     }

}

if(maxindex > minindex)
       return maxindex;
else
    return minindex;
```

}

Comment: This is a 5 year old question with multiple upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw: Also gets 100% on codility and it's easy to understand with only one HashMap

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8

    int firstCoveringPrefix = 0;
    //HashMap stores unique keys
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(!hm.containsKey(A[i])){
            hm.put( A[i] , i );
            firstCoveringPrefix = i;
        }
    }
    return  firstCoveringPrefix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the this answer in JavaScript but didn't find it so I convert the Java answer to javascript and got 93%

```
function solution(A) {
  result=0;
  temp = [];
  for(i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    if (!temp.includes(A[i])){
        temp.push(A[i]);
        result=i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
import java.util.*;

// you can use System.out.println for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

    class Solution {
        public int solution(int[] A) {
            // write your code in Java SE 8
            Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
                if (!s.contains(A[i])) {
                    s.add(A[i]);
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            return index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the question was not about how to debug a program.